# Geometry of anticommutation relations

Tags: fermions, geometry, phase-space, anticommutator

I am asking this question as a mathematician trying to understand quantum theory, so please forgive my naivety.

Systems satisfying the canonical commutation relations are naturally modeled with symplectic geometry: for example, in the discrete setting, there is a deep connection between the stabilizer formalism and affine symplectic geometry.

Is there a analogous geometry which naturally models systems satisfying the anticommutation relations?

Comment: I have not thouroughly read the book https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7ztswr but there are two chapters that develop, in parallel, the theory of fermionic fields and bosonic fields; in one, the symplectic aspect is developped, so you might find your answer by reading both chapters simultaneously!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algebra of a finite set of anticommuting $a_k$ and $a^\dagger_k$ is naturally connected with the orthogonal group. In particular the set
$$
\gamma^{2n-1}=\hat a_n^{\dagger}+ \hat a_n, \nonumber\\
\gamma^{2n} = i(\hat a_n^\dagger-\hat a_n),
$$
$n=1,\ldots N$ generates the Clifford algebra ${\rm Cl}_{2N}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. More generally, in classical Hamiltonian formalism with [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/supernumber)-valued variables, the phase space is a [supermanifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold) with a [super-Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_superalgebra) $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{SPB}$.
2. The super-Poisson bracket corresponds to a [super-commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) $\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\cdot,\cdot]_{SC}$ upon quantization. The super-commutator is a commutator (an anticommutator) in the Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd) sector, respectively.
3. In super-[Darboux coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem), the [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) ([CAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras)) of the Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd) coordinates is given by an antisymmetric (symmetric) matrix, leading to [Weyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) ([Clifford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra)) algebras, associated with with [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) ([indefinite orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group)) symmetry groups, respectively.